# Problem in analyzing Leak instrument in ipad

Tags: ipad, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

I am using the leak instrument first time.
i am getting two leaks in my code, when i saw the source code then it shows at these two bold statements....

```
- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame
{
    [self LoadMoviePlayer];

    **self= [super initWithFrame:frame];**  
    if (self==[super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        CAEAGLLayer* eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer*) self.layer;
        eaglLayer.opaque = YES;

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (UIApplication*) application
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    m_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds];
    **m_view = [[GLView alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds];**

    [m_window addSubview: m_view];
    [m_window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

don't know what to do next to solve the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From all I can see, the first leak happens when you execute code in an init without being initialized (your `[super initWithFrame:]` happens after your `[self loadMoviePlayer]`), the second, on first sight, seems to be m_view being allocated, but not released, you might solve it using:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

m_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds];
m_view = [[GLView alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds];

[m_window addSubview: m_view];
[m_view release];
[m_window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This should work, since the m_view has already being added to the window (and therefore retained).

Comment: I am releasing m_view in the dealloc functions, I don't know why but when i comment the "self= [super initWithFrame:frame];" line then the problem is solved. i have checked the self value and its not null at the point self.loadmoviePlayer is called, anybody have any idea about my problem.

Comment: The allocation of m_view will put its retain count to 1, the addSubView of the window will put it to 2. The dealloc of your component will release it to 1, but as long as you don't remove it from the window or do not release the window, its retain count stays 1.

Comment: Also.. the idea behind that loadMoviePlayer line was: do it *after* you did the [super initWithFrame:] in that if() block, to be precisely. If you create instances of objects in an object that hasn't been fully initialized (which is exactly what you do here) the behaviour is mostly defined as in "you don't want to go that way". You already set properties of the layer in the if() block, why not loading that movie player in that if() block as well?